# How to mirror a queue in ActiveMQ Artemis

Tags: activemq-artemis

I don't know how to setup mirrors in my ActiveMQ Artemis broker.
Every message should be duplicated as described [here](https://activemq.apache.org/mirrored-queues), but the question is how to do that?

I tried using a non-exclusive divert, but it didn't work. I defined this in `broker.xml`:

```xml
<addresses>
  <address name="source.AA">
    <multicast>
      <queue name="source.AA"/>
    </multicast>
  </address>
  <address name="destination.AA">
    <multicast>
      <queue name="destination.AA"/>
    </multicast>
  </address>
</addresses>

<diverts>
  <divert name="divert-AA">
    <routing-name>divert-AA</routing-name>
    <address>source.AA</address>
    <forwarding-address>destination.AA</forwarding-address>
    <exclusive>false</exclusive>
  </divert>
</diverts>
```

However, the message is not replicated. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How are you producing the message? How are you confirming the message was diverted properly (or not)?

Comment: Any update here?

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration actually works fine on Artemis 2.16.0. I would suggest to look at how you are producing messages to that multicast queue.

```sh
# after server start
$ bin/artemis queue stat --url tcp://localhost:61616 --user admin --password admin | grep .AA
|destination.AA           |destination.AA           |0              |0             |0              |0                |0              |0               |MULTICAST    |
|source.AA                |source.AA                |0              |0             |0              |0                |0              |0               |MULTICAST    |

# after sending 4 messages
$ bin/artemis queue stat --url tcp://localhost:61616 --user admin --password admin | grep .AA
|destination.AA           |destination.AA           |0              |4             |4              |0                |0              |0               |MULTICAST    |
|source.AA                |source.AA                |0              |4             |4              |0                |0              |0               |MULTICAST    |
```